# changing width based on screen resolution same as dailymotion videos

Tags: jquery, css, browser, screen

I saw in daily-motion videos a cool one open below URL and on top of the video there a option *"turn lights off"* , except video everything will be in black .

The cool thing is on resizing the window resolution even the black dimmer dynamically changes, can anyone know how they are doing this.

I want to implement something like [**this**](http://www.dailymotion.com/video/xwpyhs_twinkle-twinkle-little-star_music?search_algo=2#.UPJ15eimDWY) based on the window resize in jquery or javascript.

Answer (score 0):

there is a event for this.

```
$(window).resize(function(evt) { 
   // your handling code here 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply this style to the video -

```
#video{
z-index:3;
}
```

And make a black layer -

```
<div id="bl">
</div>
```

The black layer's style -

```
#bl{
background-color:black;
opacity:0.9;
z-index:2;
visibility:hidden;
width:100%;height:100%;
}
```

And JS -

```
$('#btn').click(function(){ 
  $('#bl').css('visibility','visible'); 
});
```

Where #btn is the id of the turn off the lights button.
And please select a correct answer in each of your questions.